# Set same color as prev row if data matches otherwise different color when rows are dynamically created

Tags: html, jquery, css, django

I need to set same color as previous row if data matches otherwise use a different color when rows .
The code works if the rows, cells and text within cells are hardcoded as here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121593/set-same-color-as-prev-row-if-data-matches-otherwise-different-color but produces alternating colouring when the rows, cells and text are dynamically generated.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var c = 0;
  $("#tblExport tbody tr").each(function () {
      var $item = $("td:first", this);
      var $prev = $(this).prev().find('td:first');

      if ($prev.length && $prev.text().trim() != $item.text().trim()) {
          c = 1 - c;
      }
      $(this).addClass(['zebra-even', 'zebra-odd'][c]);
  });
});
```

```css
#tblExport>tbody {
  font: normal medium/1.4 sans-serif;
}

#tblExport {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#tblExport th,td {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#tblExport th {
  background: #bfbfbf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% for product in products %}
<tr>
    <td>{{product.name}}</td>
    <td>{{product.price}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If you have an HTML/javascript/css query, please include some *rendered* HTML - not server side code.

Comment: *are dynamically generated* - do you mean generated server-side or *dynamically* generated - ie are the rows added before or after the page has loaded?   It looks like you're using server-side code, so the HTML doesn't change after being sent to the user.   So whether it's hardcoded or generated server-side has no effect on the client-side jquery.   Perhaps your `{{product.name}}` isn't what you think it is?  Please provided *rendered* HTML so that your snippet *demonstrates* the issue.